# AIC value for two models uing 96 well plate data

Tags: r

I am using Growthrate package in R to calculate maximum growth rate value. I used two models `fit_easylinear` and `fit_spline` models.
Now, I want to extract AIC value for each well after fitting two models. Any help at this moment is highly appreciated.
Dataset:

```
library(growthrates)
split_df <- split(bactgrowth,~strain+replicate+conc)
timeseries <- lapply(split_df, function(x) x$value)

df <- cbind(data.frame(time = 1:31),
            as.data.frame(timeseries))

fit_easymodel <- lapply(2:length(colnames(df)), function(x) fit_easylinear(df$time, df[[x]]))
fit_splinemodel <- lapply(2:length(colnames(df)), function(x) fit_spline(df$time, df[[x]],spar=0.5))
```

So I need to extract AIC value for `fit_easymodel` and `fit_splinemodel` and store them separately for each well.

Comment: I think there is a typeo in your `fit_splinemodel` - did you mean to use the `fit_spline` function? `spar` is not an argument in `fit_easylinear`

Comment: Yes,I am  sorry for the typo.

Comment: AIC and BIC are not applicable to these methods! Method `easylinear` is a **heuristic search method** and `fit_spline` a **nonparametric** method, based on R's `smooth.spline` function. In contrast to this, AIC/BIC would be applicable to the parametric models (`fit_growthmodel`), but the package does not support this directly.  Platereader data are highly autocorrelated, so that AIC values would be misleading.